# Azure Data Lake Gen 2 - How to opt in to "Multi-protocol access on Azure Data Lake Storage"

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-data-lake, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to use the dotnet blob API to connect to an Azure Data Lake Gen 2. I have added the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob 11.0.1` to my project (.Net Core 2.2). When I try to list blob containers in the storage account, I get the following error:

```
 'Blob API is not yet supported for hierarchical namespace accounts.'
```

According to the known issues page for Azure Data Lake Gen 2, you can get around this by enrolling in the public preview of multi-protocol access on Data Lake Storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues

My question is, how do I enroll in the preview? It's not clear from the microsoft docs page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It turns out, you have to submit a form for it.

https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR2EUNXd_ZNJCq_eDwZGaF5VURjFLTDRGS0Q4VVZCRFY5MUVaTVJDTkROMi4u