# Triggering Logic App Standard when changes to Data Lake Gen 2 occurs and deletes a table

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I want to test a simple workflow below:

1 Upload a text file to a Data Lake Gen 2 blob container, which triggers Logic Apps Standard

2 The workflow then deletes a table in the same storage account.

Workflow is below:
[image]

The problem is that the table still exists, which is supposed to be deleted.

Refs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatalake/

[Azure Data Lake Gen 2 - How to opt in to "Multi-protocol access on Azure Data Lake Storage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078318/azure-data-lake-gen-2-how-to-opt-in-to-multi-protocol-access-on-azure-data-la)

**Update: Design issues with Connectors of Logic Apps Std**

This is confusing from Logic Apps. There are two versions of Blob storage connectors. One supports (in `Azure` and must use `Stateful` workflow) Data Lake G2, the other (`Built-in` connectors) doesn't, but none of them has any information on what is supported or not supported.

Furthermore, the one that supports, ie. in `Azure` and must use `Stateful` workflow, uses **polling** not push notification, which is not the ideal solution.

`Stateless` workflow with connectors in `Azure` below, compared the one with `stateful` Workflow in `Built-in`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will be working with the Azure's Blob Trigger (When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)) but not the built-in's.(When a blob is added or modified) i.e..

[image]

Here is my logic app

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please update on my OP. What are your thoughts?